# AJAX : How to hide(secure) passing parameters values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I get the data from another HTML page through ajax call. But Can't prevent to showing of Ajax parameters values. We can get the parameter values by FireBug web tool.

Comment: the data is always show in firebug unless you can with javascript or serverside programming encode data or hash them!!

Answer (score 0):

Quoting a famous person "You can't do it."

Here's a link to fuller details of why not: 
[store api credential securely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43636407/store-api-credential-securely)

Might've missed this with the tagging being around java, but the answer to the API side is the same.